# OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC()).predict() gives continous values

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use  y_scores=OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC()).predict() on datasets 
like iris and titanic .The trouble is that I am getting y_scores as continous values.like for iris dataset I am getting :

```
[[ -3.70047231  -0.74209097   2.29720159]
 [ -1.93190155   0.69106231  -2.24974856]
.....
```

I am using the OneVsRestClassifier for other classifier models like knn,randomforest,naive bayes and they are giving appropriate results in the form of

```
[[ 0  1   0]
 [ 1   0  1]...
```

etc on the iris dataset .Please help.

Comment: Code you edit your question to include a minimal working example please?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is simply not true.

```
>>> from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC())
>>> clf.fit(iris['data'], iris['target'])
OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
          n_jobs=1)
>>> print clf.predict(iris['data'])
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2]
```

maybe you called `decision_function` instead (which would match your output dimension, as predict is supposed to return a vector, not a matrix). Then, SVM returns signed distances to each hyperplane, which is its decision function from mathematical perspective.